# Maven unable to find Java installation

Tags: maven, ubuntu

Im trying to run a maven project on a Ubuntu machine, but its unable to  find Java

```
 Compilation failure
Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
  /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/tools.jar
Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
In most cases you can change the location of your Java
installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

this is my etc/environment file

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:u$
JAVA_HOME=”/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre”
M2_HOME=”/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.0″
MAVEN_HOME=”/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.0″
M2=”/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.0/bin”
```

What additional information could i provide in order to make my question more clear?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre"` is the problem. Maven log clearly says that your path should point to JDK not just JRE. So try

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```